# How do we use mathematica to apply my average to this example?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, averages

I have [defined a set function and an average](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9usnjbqt3lj1u8y/New__Measure%20%2843%29.pdf?dl=0). If you need help understanding my definitions, let me know. I will do my best to explain.

## Question

How do I use Mathematica to apply my definition of average and solve

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[1,2]\\
\sin(x)+1 & x \in \left(\ln\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)\setminus\left\{1\right\}\right)\cap[1,2] \\
\end{cases}$$

## Attempt

I tried defining $f(x)$

```
f[x_] := x /; MatchQ[x, Between[_Rational, {0, 1}]] && Sin[x] + 1 /; 
  MatchQ[x, Between[Remove[Log[_Rational], 1], {0, 1}]]
```

But when I entered $f(1)$, I got

```
Piecewise[{1, 1 \[Element] Between[Rationals, {0, 1}]}, {Sin[1] + 1, 
1 \[Element] Between[Remove[Log[Rationals], 1], {0, 1}]}]
```

So I tried another approach. I defined the sub-functions and their sub-domains

```
f1[x_] := x;
f2[x_] := Sin[x] + 1;
B1[a_, b_] := 
  Select[Flatten[Table[c/d, {d, 1, b}, {c, 1, a}]], 
   Between[#, {1, 2}] &];
B2[a_, b_] := 
  DeleteCases[
   Select[Flatten[Table[N[Log[c/d], 8], {d, 1, b}, {c, 1, a}]], 
    Between[#, {1, 2}] &], 1, 2];
B1[100, 10];
B2[100, 10];
```

As $d/c\to \infty$ and $c\to \infty$, `B1` starts to resemble $\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,2]$ and `B2` starts to resemble $(\ln(\mathbb{Q})\setminus \{1\})\cap[1,2]$.

We then have to divide $[1,2]$ into $r$ sub-intervals and ignore the sub-intervals without a defined point.

The problem is I don't know how to take $\mu$ of the remaining sub-intervals as well as $\mu$ of $A$.

For each of the remaining $r^{\prime}$ sub-intervals (out of $r$ sub-intervals), how do we take the smallest sum of the length of $m^{\prime}$ sub-intervals, out of $m$ sub-intervals which are sub-intervals of one of $r^{\prime}$ sub-interval), where $S$ is uncountable and $A$ is uncountable or $S$ is countable/uncountable and $A$ is countable.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried in the way of code that you have written?

Comment: Hi, you deleted your previous post so I could not read your response. I as @4xel has mentioned already, the question you pose is not well defined and in addition to that, it uses mathematical 'lingo' that will not touch the expected audience. 
1. Can you re-formulate the question in a more explicit fashion?
2. Can you eliminate the jargon so that it can be more decypherable?
3. As above asked, could you provide us with your attempt?

Comment: @Alex I edited my post and changed my paper. Now things should be more clear.

Comment: @Alex I forgot to edit the link. I gave an explicit description in my new paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[out of topic]

Hi, I spent quite some time writting that for you:

https://www.reddit.com/r/mathematics/comments/hv9nju/how_do_i_explain_my_question_and_give_it_more/fysdmpt/

Which should cover a good deal of the math and presentation part (the presentation part got better in the meantime).

Since you deleted your account there and I can't DM via Steack Exchange and do not have the right to comment, an answer is all I get. So I might as well write a proper one.

[back on topic]

From the look of it, you spent hours inventing and writting new, clean math definitions. Likely, translating them to code will take hours as well, if not more. I'm not sure what kind of help you're expecting from stack exchange, but, without being too familiar with mathematica, I'd surmise there is no easy way to solve your problem. Maybe you're expecting something similar to integration tools, but you're most likely in the position where you have to build new tools, not merely using existing ones.

With that out of the way, I'd start simple. For example, f_1 and f_2 could be constant functions without changing the gist of the issue IIUC. B_1 and B_2 could be the sets of decimal numbers with odd and even numerator for example. Only then move on to more complicated examples.

I'd also try to do it by hand, hence an even bigger need for simplistic examples. If you can't explain a program with words, it's even less possible that you can code it.

Then I'd try with a very small bit: can you compute the sum in your µ? I don't understand it so I can't help, but if you can't compute that small part, you can't compute the rest.

From my understanding, Mathematica provides support for existing mathmetical notions. Depending on your goals and how gritty it gets, you might have to code for good in a "real" programming language, maybe connecting mathematica to a library you built.

To know what you have to invent and what you don't, I'd try cutting the question in very small bits. It's necessary both for you and for asking around here (or elsewhere for what matters).

Comment: Thank You very much. I wished I could award you on Reddit. I did sent my revised paper to a professor. The problem is currently I am not enrolled in a university so he would put me in the lowest of his prorities. The good news is I was sent from another professor so perhaps he will respond. I also updated my mathematica post but unfortunately someone downvoted it. Perhaps I edited to late. Thank you so much for your help!